# How to apply and remove discount for all product

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, woocommerce

I want to have two checkboxes to be displayed on the special page that is my product table, where there is a 15% discount if you click on the first checkbox and a 20% discount on all products if you click on the second checkbox.
I tried a lot but I did not succeed, I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: What happens if a user has *both* checkboxes checked?

Comment: you need to use radio button for this logic

Comment: Use select with 3 options:  none,15%,20%